# saxon including boolean itemscope value and closing source tag in html output

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm using Saxon-HE 9.6.0.1J from Saxonica to generate HTML documents (`xsl:output method="html"`). It's generally good at omitting the value of boolean attributes and closing tags for empty elements, but I've found a few situations where it fails:

1. The microdata `itemscope="itemscope"` attribute is not output as simply `itemscope`
2. empty `source` elements are given closing tags

Here is an example stylesheet that demonstrates the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" include-content-type="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>HTML test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://example.com/dummy/">
          <span itemprop="prop1">val1</span>
        </div>
        <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
          <source type="audio/mpeg" src="example.mp3" />
          <source type="audio/x-wav" src="example.wav" />
        </audio>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>
<example/>
```

Command:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:example.xml -a
```

Results:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>HTML test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://example.com/dummy/"><span itemprop="prop1">val1</span></div>
      <audio autoplay controls>
         <source type="audio/mpeg" src="example.mp3"></source>
         <source type="audio/x-wav" src="example.wav"></source>
      </audio>
   </body>
</html>
```

As demonstrated, `meta` is properly empty but `source` is not, and the values for `autoplay` and `controls` are properly omitted but not for `itemscope`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing the solution to tell Saxon how to treat those elements and attributes?  I've searched the docs on saxonica.com and questions here for a clue, but not found anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `version="5.0"` on the output element , perhaps then the serializer recognizes HTML5 elements like source.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the source element, but not the itemscope attribute (as explained in Michael Kay's answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "source" element is recognized as an empty element if you specify version="5.0" on xsl:output.

The list of attributes that Saxon recognizes as boolean attributes when you specify method="html" version="5.0" comes from here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1

which does not include "itemscope". I'm afraid I can't help you with the history of how it comes to be present in some flavours of HTML and not in the W3C flavour, but Saxon inevitably follows the W3C specs.

Perhaps we should provide some way of extending the list (if you're really keen you can do it by writing your own serializer factory class that customizes the Saxon serializer, but that's serious hackery).

Comment: Thank you! A way to extend the list (maybe a PI?) would be most welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick update: In XSLT 3.0, you can specify the @html-version attribute, which you can set to 5.0 if you want to use XHTML5. Doing so solved the issue of at `<source>` for me while still using `@method="xhtml"`.